# How to create the 3-Dimensional Nx.Tensor from 4-Dimensional Nx.Tensor (in elixir)?

Tags: elixir, tensor

I need to create 3-D tensor `m` from two matrices `a`, `b` (two 2-D tensors) such that
`m[i][k][j] = a[i][k] * b[k][j]`
(in fact the dimension order doesn't matter here so it could be also:)
`m[k][i][j] = a[i][k] * b[k][j]`   or
`m[i][j][k] = a[i][k] * b[k][j]`.

I found the way how to create 4-D tensor `n`, `n[i][l][k][j] = a[i][l]*b[k][j]` and now I need to slice/gather/take somehow only that elements where `l==k`.

Is there any way to slice `n`, or create `m` in other better way?

```
a_mat = Nx.random_uniform({5,5}, names: [:i, :l])
b_mat = Nx.random_uniform({5,5}, names: [:k, :j]) 
n_tensor = Nx.dot(a_mat,[], b_mat,[])
m_tensor = ???
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration I think that the best approach is:

```
m_tensor = Nx.dot( Nx.transpose(a_mat), [], [0], b_mat, [],[0])
```

it will create a tensor where

```
m[k][i][j] = a[i][k] * b[k][j]
```